# Secure text inputs for connection string in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, security, connection-string

I have a WPF application that can make a connection with a SQL Server to retrieve data.

The user has the possibility to write the server's name and a username and password in TextBox if he doesn't use integrated security. The connection string is built with the inputs:

```
    public string GetConnectionString(string name, string server, bool isWindowsAuth = false, string user = null, string password = null)
    {
        string connectionMode = "";
        if(isWindowsAuth == true)
            connectionMode = "Integrated Security=True";
        else
            connectionMode = string.Format("User Id = {0}; Password = {1}; ", user, password);

        return string.Format(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[name].ConnectionString, server, connectionMode);
    }
```

I'm new in learning security, and I'm searching for a proper way to secure that, because I'm not checking user input for the server's name and credentials, and I was wondering what can happen regarding security, and if XSS is possible, or things like that.

Connection string encrypting isn't what I'm referring to or searching for.

Thank you.

Comment: securestring works very well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're not putting that user input into a database query (susceptible to sql injection) or directly back into the browser (susceptible to cross site scripting because he could put in actual javascript or html code) I don't think there is a security risk. If the user puts non working credentials in, the database connection should simply not work.